# What Plugin goes "type" of a FieldStorageConfig type?

Tags: entities, 8

I have a module creating a field type. It works.  I can create and add the field through the admin UI.  However, I am trying to update a content type with hook_update_N and change a field from entity reference to my field type. I am creating the FieldConfig and FieldStorageConfig like this

```
$field_storage = FieldStorageConfig::create([
       'field_name' => 'content_category',
       'entity_type' => 'node',
       'type' => 'my_field_type',
    ]);

$field = FieldConfig::create([
      'field_storage' => $field_storage,
      'field_name' => 'content_category',
      'bundle' => 'story',
      'label' => $label,
      'settings' => array('display_summary' => TRUE),
      'entity_type' => 'node',
    ]);
    $field->save();
```

This results in an error that says

```
The "my_field_type" plugin does not exist
```

but i can  create a field of type "my_field_type" and when I export configurations for my field created through the UI  the type says "my_field_type"

So What plugin is it looking for in the "type" field of a fieldConfigStorage?  In my Plugin folder of my module the Formatter.php  Field.php and Widget.php  which of these is the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

My Bug was actually in

```
entitity_get_form_display()->setComponent('field', array(
type=>my_field_type))
```

it should have been

```
entitity_get_form_display()->setComponent('field', array(
type=>my_field_type_widget))
```